# For a given number N i have to find all the prime numbers it's consisting of

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

Need a suggestion for an algorithm.

For a given number N i have to find all the prime numbers it's consisting of, like this:

```
N = 49
49 = 7 ^ 2
N = 168
168 = (2 ^ 3) * (3 ^ 1) * (7 ^ 1)
```

If you want to help me even more you can write the algo in c++.

Thanks.

Comment: "If you want to help me even more you can write the algo in c++." Nobody is really helping you if you never actually have to try or learn anything. I wish programming were that easy: "Do this for me...done!"

Comment: Anyway, what you're looking for is called prime factorization. There exist many algorithms, it's a very important topic in number theory and security. A trivial algorithm is by division: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way is trial division.  Basically just try dividing n by each prime number up to sqrt(n).  For large numbers, this is a very slow algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

For more sophisticated algorithms, try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: "For large numbers, this is a very slow algorithm". Technically, for numbers with large prime factors this is a very slow algorithm. Since he wants the full factorization, the natural thing is to divide by each factor as you find it, so that you only ever reach all the way to sqrt(n) if n is prime. In this way you can factorise 2^31 with 31 trial divisions, whereas 2^31-1 takes about 2^16 trial divisions (or fewer once you start skipping even numbers after 2, etc).

Comment: @Steve: Actually, the suggested algorithm tries only primes, so you'd be testing a few thousand, not tens of thousands candidates. But as stated it's wrong: it does find that 7 divides 49, _but not how often_. The two suggestions combined do work, e.g. 147 => 2^0 * 147 => 2^0 * 3^1 * 49 = 2^0 * 3^1 * 5^0 * 49 = 2^0 * 3^1 * 5^0 * 7^1 * 7 = 2^0 * 3^1 * 5^0 * 7^2 (4 and 6 are skipped because they're not primes)

Comment: @MSalters: fair point, I missed that. Calculating all prime numbers up to sqrt(n) for arbitrary n is left as an exercise for the reader, but that's where fixed-size types come in handy.